# Сохранить картинку со страницы открытой в Webbrowser

Tags: delphi-7

Нужно сохранить картинку со страницы открытой в Webbrowser, нашел вот такое решение:

```
var
  body, imgs, controlRange: olevariant;
begin
        body := wb1.OleObject.document.body;
        imgs := wb1.OleObject.document.images.item(i);//нужный img
        controlRange := body.createControlRange;
        controlRange.add(imgs);
        controlRange.execCommand('Copy', False, EmptyParam);//копируем
        if ClipBoard.HasFormat(CF_BITMAP) then begin
          img1.Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromClipboardFormat(cf_BitMap, ClipBoard.GetAsHandle(cf_Bitmap), 0);//вставляем
          Clipboard.Clear;// очищаем буфер
        end;
end;
```

на строке

```
controlRange.add(imgs);
```

выдает:

> "Method 'add' not supported by automation object"

как заставить этот код работать? ОС Windows 7, IE 11.

Может кто подскажет другое решение, как сохранить картинку?

Comment: То есть вы скопировали код неизвестно откуда, и хотите, чтобы вам его привели в рабочее состояние? Вариант почитать документацию и разобраться вы не рассматриваете?

Comment: Ну было бы неплохо если бы вы подсказали решение, если конечно знаете в чем проблема! Или вы только критику наводить можете? Если бы я мог разобраться самостоятельно то наверное не просил бы помощи!

Comment: Видите ли какое дело. Если мы за вас всё перепишем целиком чтобы работало, то вы ничему не научитесь и не станете более опытным специалистом. Это же плохо. А мы вам плохого не желаем, потому и не делаем работу за вас.

Comment: Спасибо за заботу =) Однако я и не прошу переписать код.Просто можно хоть что то подсказать? Пока только два пустых, бессмысленных комментария....

Comment: Было бы полезно, если бы вы у помянули версию ОС и InternetExplorer. На IE9 работает.

Comment: ОС Windows 7, IE 11. Вот мне и интересен этот момент, прочитал на многих форумах - у кого то этот код работает без проблем , у других нет.

Comment: @stud: Вы не допускаете мысли, что качество комментариев коррелирует с качеством вопроса?

Comment: VladD я придерживаюсь такой точки зрения: если нечего сказать то лучше не мусорили бы своими комментариями! А то вроде бы и ответить хочется и по теме сказать нечего ( это я про ваши комментарии)